# Formating all tables in file with style

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working with some kind of documentation at the moment, which consists of lots and lots of tables. And as you may have guessed by now, I need to format them with a certain style.
So, there's a VBA macro exclusively made for that purpose - it creates required style and then applies it to all tables in the file. But now it seems to be a problem when I'm working with large document.
So, let's see working code, ommiting part, where style is created:

```
Dim oTable As Table
For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
oTable.Select
Selection.Tables(1).ApplyStyleDirectFormatting ("FooStyle")
Selection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitFixed)
Selection.Tables(1).ApplyStyleRowBands = True
With Selection.Tables(1).Borders
    .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .InsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
    .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
End With

'Make a list for last row of the table
Selection.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=8, Column:=1).Range.Select
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(2)
Next
```

So this code works nicely for documents less than 600 pages. Otherwise it stops at line

```
.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
```

with run-time error 4605 telling stories about memory and disk space. I've done some research and found [this awesome thread](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1525289) telling about downsides of Selection. Then following given advice and changed macro's code a bit, resulting in following:

```
Dim lTbl As Long
For lTbl = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
ActiveDocument.Tables(lTbl).ApplyStyleDirectFormatting ("BarStyle")
ActiveDocument.Tables(lTbl).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitFixed)
ActiveDocument.Tables(lTbl).ApplyStyleRowBands = True
With ActiveDocument.Tables(lTbl).Borders
    .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .InsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
    .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
End With

'Make a list for last row of the table
ActiveDocument.Tables(lTbl).Cell(Row:=8, Column:=1).Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(2)
Next
```

Yeah, creepily long line. Nope, nothing changed. Seems like there're no more selections, but still the same error at the same place. So then i tried changing part where debugger stopped when error appeared:

```
For Each oCell In ActiveDocument.Tables(lTbl).Range.Cells
    oCell.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    oCell.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
    Next
```

To no avail - still got the same problem. At this point I decided to do some experiments and removed next to last line of the code (that long-a** line)... and voila - macro works like a charm, no errors, no complaints, nothing. For arguments sake I tried making same changes to first version of this macro and results was the same - seems like it was that line's fault all along.
So leaving it like this is not a solution, as the numbered list in last row is a must. Then, what should I do to this macro that it doesn't pop up this error?

Comment: +1 from me for very good written question. However, I can't experience your problem as I have not such a long document. What happen if the code stop with 4605, you wait a sec and try to push it with F8 key? What if you loop twice- first to set style, second to apply listformat? There should be a question of Word version, too?

Comment: No matter how much I try or wait same error remains and debugger won't budge a single line. Not only that, but also after force-ending macro execution all interaction with Word is disabled (even in new documents unrelated to this one). And as for setting loop twice... it actually works. It's a little bit slower and scales in time with my first version of macro, but at least in the end I get file, not error. Dunno how will it behave with larger files, but for now - thanks for help, maybe you should post it as answer.

Comment: By the way, referring to 'Application stopped interaction'- are you using anywhere in your code `Application.ScreenUpdating= False` which could make the problem? I only guess there could be something like that. Then, if you stop macro on error try to set it back to True using IDE `Immediate` Window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of problem can be solved by splitting task into two loops. First iteration will change the table formatting. Second iteration will add `ListFormat` where expected.

Of course, as a result we get slower subroutine but finally we get what we need.